# Getting the image type from 'getHitTestResult()' in a webview

Tags: android, webview

I have a web view that when a long click on links or images, a context menu has appeared. when I click on google search result links, **webView.getHitTestResult()** method return image type. It's generally very wrong.

[image]
how to fix it?

It is possible I use a custom type instead use **WebView.HitTestResult.IMAGE_TYPE**?

My *onCreateContextMenu* is:

```
 @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    WebView.HitTestResult result = webView.getHitTestResult();

    if (result.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.IMAGE_TYPE ||
            result.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE) {

        menu.setHeaderTitle(result.getExtra());
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Image").setOnMenuItemClickListener(handler);

    } else if (result.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.ANCHOR_TYPE ||
            result.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.SRC_ANCHOR_TYPE) {

        menu.setHeaderTitle(result.getExtra());
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Link").setOnMenuItemClickListener(handler);

    }
}
```